Time interval function in google sheets
If the total count and time interval is given, break the time interval in 30 mins and assign the number from total count. What is the formula for this in google sheets
I could not find the solution as I am new to google sheet

Suppose count is 10 and time interval 30 minutes and start time is 8:00 AM then try ={SEQUENCE(10),SEQUENCE(10,1,TIME(8,0,0),TIME(0,30,0))}.

Formula to distribute a total count across 30-minutes interval in Google Sheets
You can use the following formula to distribute a total count across 30-minute intervals in Google Sheets, Assume your total count is in cell A1.
In cell B1, enter the formula: =A1 + TIME(0 , 30 , 0) where total_intervals is the number of 30-minute intervals within your total time.
Please note that the given time is an assumption. If you have a total count, you can include the cell reference in the formula (Ex. =A2)
Formula used
For a single cell you can use this formula.
=A2 + TIME(0, 30, 0)

A2: This is the starting time from which the intervals will be calculated.
TIME(0, 30, 0) : This creates a time value representing 30 minutes. It’s the amount of time you want to add to the starting time for each interval.
For a whole column you can use this formula.
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A + TIME(0, 30, 0))

ARRAYFORMULA : This function allows you to perform calculations over a range of cells instead of a single cell, enabling you to generate multiple results at once.
Please note that the given time is an assumption. If you have a total count, you can include the cell reference in the formula
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2 + TIME(0, 30, 0) * ROW(A2:A10))

ROW(A2:A10): This returns an array of row numbers for the range A2 to A10. For example, it will return {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}. Each row number corresponds to how many 30-minute increments to add to the starting time.
Sample Output

Reference

Time Function


Thanks for the response. But need more help on this.
There are total 20 Slots available. If we consider that there are 2 intervals of 30 minutes in time between 10-11 AM, these 2 intervals are required to be minus from total slots so that the total slot would become 18. The total slots should keep changing according to time interval we give. What formula could we use for this in Google Sheet?

Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is a new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question by including the detailed information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it.
